# Delete Row if date has already passed but not if the cell is blank VBA

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

I am trying to delete a row only if there is a date that is past today, but not if it is in the future or blank.  Right now I am having a hard time getting the code to not delete the row if there is no blank because I want to keep the rows with no dates.

```
Sub deleteSpudedWells()
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim ctr As Integer

Dim currentCell As Range
Dim valueOfDColumn
Dim NoNSpudedWells As Boolean



 lastRow = 300
 firstRow = 10

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 With Sheets("NDIC Renewals")
     For ctr = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
         Set currentCell = .Cells(ctr, 4)
         valueOfDColumn = currentCell.Value
         NoNSpudedWells = valueOfDColumn >= Date


         If Not NoNSpudedWells Then
             Debug.Print "deleting row of cell " + currentCell.Address
             currentCell.EntireRow.Delete
         End If
     Next
 End With
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another condition to your if:

```
If Not NoNSpudedWells AND valueOfDColumn <> 0 Then
```

If `currentCell` is blank, it's value will = 0.

Comment: if the cell is blank, wouldn't it be null ""?

Comment: @bonCodigo No, technically it will be empty. Which when used as a number evaluates to 0. So, in that regard it will = 0. It would also = "". In that regard your answer is no more correct or incorrect than mine. I was simply indicating a way to get the described result with as little modification to the OP code as possible.

Comment: I was checking, `cell.value returns null`, however as you said based on the type it evaluates then value gets the mask ;) Thanks +1

Comment: @bonCodigo Technically, that is false. `cell.value` returns `Empty` if the cell is blank. That is not the same as Null. Null does not convert to an empty string or 0. Empty does both of those things. Additionally, `Isnull(Empty)` returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
    For ctr = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
         Set currentCell = .Cells(ctr, 4)
         valueOfDColumn = currentCell.Value               

         If NOT (valueOfDColumn >= Date or currentCell.Value = "") Then
             Debug.Print "deleting row of cell " + currentCell.Address
             currentCell.EntireRow.Delete
         End If
     Next
```

**BTW**
It's best to declare your `valueOfDColumn` as `Date` instead of leaving it to be a default `variant` :)

Comment: Upvoted this because I dislike when OPs answer their own questions and cite other answers as their reference. But then I realized it was wrong so I had to fix it for you. ;-) It'd be less confusing to remove the Not and have `valueOfDColumn < Date AND currentCell.Value <> ""`

Comment: @DanielCook OP seems to have been doing that.... In terms of the typo I noticed thanks, `Date` and `<> ""`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to BonCodigo It gave me an idea and i was able to adjuct the code to work. Needed to read this to make the code run properly **valueOfDColumn** = ""

```
 Sub deleteSpudedWells()
     Dim lastRow As Integer
     Dim firstRow As Integer
     Dim ctr As Integer

     Dim currentCell As Range
     Dim valueOfDColumn
     Dim NoNSpudedWells As Boolean

     lastRow = 300
     firstRow = 10

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     With Sheets("NDIC Renewals")
         For ctr = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
             Set currentCell = .Cells(ctr, 4)
             valueOfDColumn = currentCell.Value
             NoNSpudedWells = valueOfDColumn >= Date Or valueOfDColumn = ""

             If Not NoNSpudedWells Then
                 Debug.Print "deleting row of cell " + currentCell.Address
                 currentCell.EntireRow.Delete
             End If
         Next
     End With
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: then you may 'tick' as answered ;)